# Cartesian products of indexed sets: how do I unpack the LHS?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$\cup_{(i, j)\in I\times J} (A_{i} \times B_{j}) $ = $(\cup_{i\in I} A_{i}) \times (\cup_{j\in J} B_{j})$

I know and wish to prove the above statement is true. But how may I unpack the LHS of the equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that an "elementwise" proof will be easiest.

So consider an element of the LHS: since the LHS is a set of ordered pairs we'll call the element $(x,y)$.  If
$$(x,y)\in \bigcup_{(i, j)\in I\times J} (A_{i} \times B_{j})$$
then, unpacking the union,
$$(x,y)\in A_{i} \times B_{j}\quad\hbox{for some}\quad (i,j)\in I\times J\ .$$
Unpacking the Cartesian products, this means
$$x\in A_i\ \hbox{and}\ y\in B_j\quad\hbox{for some}\quad i\in I\ \hbox{and}\ j\in J\ .$$
Since $A_i\subseteq \bigcup_{i\in I} A_{i}$, and similarly for $B_j$, we have
$$x\in \bigcup_{i\in I} A_{i}\quad\hbox{and}\quad y\in \bigcup_{j\in J} B_{j}\ .$$
Therefore
$$(x,y)\in \Bigl(\bigcup_{i\in I} A_{i}\Bigr) \times \Bigl(\bigcup_{j\in J} B_{j}\Bigr)\ ,$$
that is, $(x,y)\in {\rm RHS}$.  This shows ${\rm LHS}\subseteq {\rm RHS}$, now you have to show that ${\rm RHS}\subseteq {\rm LHS}$.

Comment: Got it! Thank you David.